# How to create extensible Electron applications?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, extensibility

[Atom](https://atom.io/) and [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) are probably the biggest Electron apps so far and they're both quite extensible, and the are other smaller examples like [N1](https://github.com/nylas/N1). By extensible I mean, they support plug-ins.

The problem is: I thought I would find something on Google on how to make an Electron app extensible, or something on those cool "awesome" lists, but I found nothing. Besides, digging into these apps source-code would take a while.

What I'm looking for (OR):

- A built in feature that I'm not aware of
- A library like `electron-extensible` (fake name)
- A guideline

So, how do I make an Electron application extensible?

Comment: Its a bit late to reply here. But I found a good answer for this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39185524/how-to-create-extensible-electron-applications

Answer (score 0):

If you're the one writing the app, would be the one to create the layout/conventions used in the plugins.

That being said there are many ways you could do that, one being dynamicly require statements for substitute functionalities.

Coming from an OO background, I would recommend looking into Factory and Conposite design patterns.

Here are some electron resources: https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-electron/blob/master/readme.md